# How to fill form by clicking search bar dropdown in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have created a search functionality in a component in Laravel which is showing the data from the MySQL database in a dropdown which I implement by using **Typeahead Js** using this [website tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/create-autocomplete-search-in-laravel-with-typeahead-js/).

When I click on one of the search result it should fill the below field related entries from the database.

I tried by doing it through  **AJAX**. when it didn't work out I tried to do it with **Vue Axios** (I linked all the required CDN links in my app file). But I'm new to both of these techs so don't know where I'm making the mistake.

My Laravel version is 9 and Php is 7.4^ (they are project requirements).

This is the dropdown browser image as it's fetching the data

[image: searchbar]

This is just the one section of the template I'm working right now

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('incident.store') }}">
    @csrf

    {{--* Injured Person --}}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> {{ __('Injured Person') }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" id="app">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label>Search CNIC</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ __('Search   CNIC') }}"
                        name="ip_search_cnic" v-model='message' id="ip_cnic">
                    <div class=" input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="search_button"
                            v-on:click=" searchInjuredPerson ">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ __('Name') }}"
                        name="ip_name" id="ip_name" v-model="injuredPerson.name" required     autofocus>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label>CNIC</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ __('CNIC') }}"
                        name="ip_cnic" id="ip_cnic" v-model="injuredPerson.cnic" required autofocus>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="ip_address" rows="9" id="ip_address"
                        placeholder="{{ __('Address') }}" v-model="injuredPerson.address"
                        required></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="{{ __('Phone Number') }}"
                        name="ip_phone_number" id="ip_phone_number" v-model="injuredPerson.phoneNumber"
                        required autofocus>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label>Date of Birth</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="{{ __('Date of Birth') }}"
                        name="ip_date_of_birth" id="ip_date_of_birth"
                        v-model="injuredPerson.dateOfBirth" required autofocus>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label>Age</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="ip_age" id="ip_age"
                        placeholder="{{ __('Age') }}" v-model="injuredPerson.age" required autofocus>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

I tried to do it with ajax and vue Axios multiple time. So don't know where's the problem. But this is the code for Ajax.

```
@section('javascript')
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
// Handle search input keyup event
$('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
var searchCnic = $(this).val();

// Make an AJAX request to fetch matching injured persons
$.ajax({
url: '/incident/search',
type: 'POST',
data: { ip_cnic: searchCnic },
success: function(response) {
// Process the response and populate the dropdown list
var dropdownList = $('#searchResults');
dropdownList.empty();

$.each(response, function(index, injuredPerson) {
dropdownList.append($('
<option />', {
value: injuredPerson.id,
text: injuredPerson.cnic
}));
});
}
});
});

// Handle dropdown selection change event
$('#searchResults').change(function() {
var selectedInjuredPersonId = $(this).val();

// Fetch the injured person details using AJAX
$.ajax({
url: '/incident/' + selectedInjuredPersonId,
type: 'GET',
success: function(response) {
// Populate the form fields with the retrieved data
$('#ip_name').val(response.name);
$('#ip_cnic').val(response.cnic);
$('#ip_address').val(response.address);
$('#ip_phone_number').val(response.phone_number);
$('#ip_date_of_birth').val(response.date_of_birth);
$('#ip_age').val(response.age);
}
});
});
});
</script>


@endsection
```

The below is my web.php route

```
    //Showing dropdown for of fetched data by typehead
        Route::get('/home', [TypeaheadController::class, 'index']);
        Route::get('/autocomplete-search', [TypeaheadController::class, 'autocompleteSearch']);

   // For filling the form fields
        Route::post('incident/search', 'IncidentController@search')->name('incident.search');
        Route::get('incident/{injured_person}', 'IncidentController@showPerson')->name('incident.show');
```

The below code snippet is for my **search controller**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $cnic = $request->input('ip_cnic');

    // Perform the search query
    $results = InjuredPerson::where('ip_cnic', 'LIKE', '%' . $cnic . '%')->get();

    return response()->json($results);
}

public function showPerson(InjuredPerson $injured_person)
{
    return response()->json($injured_person);
}
```

Tried:  I want to search some data in search bar. it showed a dropdown but when i clicked on it to fill the form field entries below. It did not work out.

I expect that when i click on the dropdown result and clicked  on it should fill the form entries with the fetched data from the database.

Comment: Hi , where is `searchInput` in your html ?

Comment: @Swati , sorry I forget to change it. It's the id name of search bar input label. You can change it to `ip_cnic`. I did the change but it's still not working.

Comment: Also, what about `searchResults` not seeing this in html ?

Comment: @Swati, I'm really sorry. I don't know about it . I took help from an AI tool because I'm new to AJAX and vue. You can change or modify the code.
 I was just trying to achieve a form filled functionality after clicked the search result. So that it filled my form section..

Comment: @Swati, if you need any other code snippet let me know. And thanks alot to you for looking into my issue.

Comment: You are missing `searchResults` element in your DOM and not sure if that should be select tag because in your current ajax code you are appending option tag in your `searchResults` . Instead , change that to `ul` tag and append `li` . Lastly , use click event to assign value to other form inputs.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help and time @Swati , I have resolved the issue . I have done it by vue Axios by creating a separate template . But thanks alot agian.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ip_name').val = response.name;
```